How is defconstants and symbol macros handled in Common Lisp in regard to space?
When interfacing with C libraries, in this case win32 in particular, there may be a large number of defined constants. In a C/C++ program these are just literal numbers when compiler sees them, the symbols are compiled away so to say. Typically it is preprocessor that does the substitution in case of #define's. In newer C++ standards there is a move away from the preprocessor, but that is not subject of this question.
My question is, how are constants defined with defconstant in CL treated in regard to memory and is there a way to skip the cost of allocating a symbol for each? Other than typing the literal value in the code of course.
In SBCL, describe says this:
(describe 'cl:defconstant)
COMMON-LISP:DEFCONSTANT
  [symbol]

DEFCONSTANT names a macro:
  Lambda-list: (NAME VALUE &OPTIONAL (DOC NIL))
  Documentation:
    Define a global constant, saying that the value is constant and may be
      compiled into code. If the variable already has a value, and this is not
      EQL to the new value, the code is not portable (undefined behavior). The
      third argument is an optional documentation string for the variable.
  Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;MACROS.LISP

If I understand correctly: "may be compiled into code" means the value of the variable defined as constant will be used during the compilation instead of looking up the symbol. So far so good.
However, if I am correct here, I am still spending the space for the symbol structure to store the variable, since the system has to be able to lookup stored doc string and give the information about the symbol. As an example:
(defconstant +above-normal-priority-class+   #x00008000)

Than I can stil get the value via (symbol-value '+above-normal-priority-class+).
Is this because I am using the system via repl, so it is not optimized away, or does the symbol always exist during the entire runtime of the program? The real example is here:
(defconst +above-normal-priority-class+   #x00008000)
(defconst +below-normal-priority-class+   #x00004000)
(defconst +realtime-priority-class+       #x00000100)
(defconst +high-priority-class+           #x00000080)
(defconst +idle-priority-class+           #x00000040)
(defconst +normal-priority-class+         #x00000020)
(defconst +process-mode-background-begin+ #x00200000)
(defconst +process-mode-background-end+   #x00100000)

(defconst is just short for defconstant here)
I don't need to attach any other data to those constants and I need them only at the compile-time. It seems quite expensive to use a symbol just to store a number for this particular purpose. In other words, I don't want all those Windows constants from the large win32 API in the process image when I run the program.
The closest I am aware of to C's #define is define-symbol-macro. If I do something like this:
(define-symbol-macro some-number 1)

I can use some-number, as if it was a symbol, but at least, it does not appear as a symbol. For example (symbol-value 'some-number) says that some-number is unbound, as it should since, I guess this one was interned by the reader.
Even symbol macro has to be stored somewhere, so the reader can find it, but I am not sure where and how they store them. My question is, are symbol macros also stored in the compiled program, just so we can lookup the info about a particular symbol macro, or are they available only in the compiler during the compilation?
I don't understand really how CL is compiled, and what is more efficient to use here, or are both equal in terms of efficiency? Those named constants are used just to not type magic numbers all over the place, but I don't need them as symbols, since they are not used for any other operations.
Can someone explain what is good practice here, and perhaps how these things work under the hood?

Symbol macros must be replaced at compile time. Constants can be, but aren't required to be.

Common Lisp is a standardized language, with very different implementations.
Often the specifics of the development environment(s) (-> how to determine symbols, which are no longer needed and how to get rid of them) are not defined in the standard.
Specifics of the development environment related features for the various implementations are to be found in the respective user guides. See for example the SBCL manual.
Files are being compiled by the function COMPILE-FILE. Now we can imagine that:

there is a file with your constants foo.lisp"

and a file using those constants bar.lisp


One could now start an sbcl and compile&load the file foo.lisp. Then one compiles the file bar.lisp using the same session.
Then we start a new sbcl and load the compiled code for the file bar.
Now the questions are:

would it be necessary to load the file foo? Probably not, depending on optimization settings.

would sbcl know the constant symbols from the file foo.lisp? Probably yes. One might need to set the debug & space optimizations to 0 and set some other settings (like not recording source locations or similar...), to prevent that. I have no clear answer for that, but some sbcl expert might have.


Other implementations may have different behavior. For example I could imagine that a treeshaker (in the Lisp world, that's a tool, which removes unused code & data) in some other implementation would be able to remove such symbols for the purpose of application delivery.

Although the compiler can inline constants, it's not required to, so you have to load foo.bin in the new environment. It also has to be loaded so you can use something like (symbol-value '+above-normal-priority-class+). The treeshaker is usually used when converting a running Lisp environment into an executable.
